# Android imageview to bitmap

Tags: android, gridview, bitmap, imageview

I have an app in which i use a function to change a color into another color.The function works only on bitmaps, but it works great.

I want to implement the same function inside of a gridview. Therefore i converted the imageview to a bitmap, applied the function, and reconverted the bitmap to an imageview but nothing happens.

```
//here i get the picture to the imageview
imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
imageView.setMaxWidth(20);
imageView.setMaxHeight(100);
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
imageView.setPadding(10,10,10,10);       

ImageView imgv=new ImageView(mContext);
imgv.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bmap = imgv.getDrawingCache();
Bitmap bmap2 = imgv.getDrawingCache();

bmap=Square3.repleceIntervalColor(bmap2, 240, 255, 240, 255, 240, 255,Project.getColor());

imageView.setImageBitmap(bmap);
```

Comment: Im not seeing in your code the connection between variables imageView, and imgv.  You setup a new imgv and get it' drawing cache, but what is in imgv at that point, nothing yet from what I can see.

Comment: i used imgv only in the idea that that was the problem.I thought that the error was because of overwritting the same ImageView.imgv and imageView have the same context in them

Comment: Also, you stated that you wished to do this for a gridview, what part of the gridview, the backing, or the cells themselves.  I see no code here for a gridview.

Comment: it's for the cells.I have images with clothing, and the function replaceIntervalColor, replaces a color with another.And i want the same function to work on the gridview which contains the different clothe items.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved.The code is corect only, that it's in the wrong place.The entire code should have been after `imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds4[position]);`.